# how to connect power bi to google big query usind direct query

Tags: connection, google-bigquery, powerbi, bigdata

I have most of my big tables (tables with over 200 M records) sitting at Google's Big Query servers and would like to use Power Bi (Desktop) for doing analytics. Found Simba´s ODBC driver, installed and configured and gained access to the datasets, but Power Bi is not giving a choice for Direct Querying the data. Instead, is trying to download it, which of course will not do it, firstly because of storage limitations on the client side, but mostly because the only reason I have the data at Big Query is to be able to use Google´s processing power. Simba´s driver specs says it should allow Direct Querying (called Direct BI) but that did not work for me.

Has anyone out there ever tried to connect BQ from Power Bi? If so could direct querying? Have any ideas or suggestion for doing this without transferring the data?

Thanks

Comment: This is likely to be closed on Stack Overflow as "too broad". I'd recommend posting this as a discussion thread in the [BigQuery Google Groups forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bigquery-discuss), as this is the perfect sort of thread for more open-ended discussion there. Stack Overflow is very focused on specific issue technical question-answer format.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a certain number of data sources supported by Power BI for DirectQuery. You can find the full list here: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-directquery-data-sources/.

However, support for Google Big Query (using either Import or DirectQuery mode) was added to Power BI Desktop in the August 2017 update. More information here: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-august-2017-feature-summary/#GoogleBigQuery

Per Miguel Llopis (program manager for Power BI), support for Google Big Query in the Power BI Service (allowing you to refresh reports using Big Query) will be coming by the end of the 2017 calendar year. See here: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7043266-support-google-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using Power BI for Big Query analysis. As of Q1 2019 Power BI still do not support project billing unless manually editing the connexion script, it does not support Sheets federated tables and do not support nested and repeated fields. Microsoft do not seems to be willing to develop the compatibility between Power BI and Big Query further.

Learn more in this article (i am the author):
https://medium.com/@remy_david/which-bi-tool-for-big-query-d9eb838ff7ad

Comment: You appear to be connecting to BigQuery from Power BI using the ODBC driver. Did you try the direct connection (“DirectQuery”) by any chance?